# How to sort a massiv array along innermost dimension?

Tags: arrays, sorting, haskell, multidimensional-array, massiv

I have an `Array r Ix2 a` such that `(Manifest r Ix2 a, Ord a)`. I'd like to sort this array on its innermost dimension - that is, sort each row internally, but not across rows. According to [this](https://github.com/lehins/massiv/issues/48#issuecomment-429843803), massiv doesn't have any sorting implemented at all. Would I have to roll my own, or can I re-use something that already exists for `Vector`s (such as `vector-algorithms` for example)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course, it would be better to roll out your own sorting and submit a PR to `massiv` library ;) But there is a way to fall back onto `vector-algorithms` package. I was curious how I'd do it efficiently and here it is, along with automatic parallelization of sorting each row:

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts    #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies        #-}
module Examples.SortRows where

import           Data.Massiv.Array                 as A
import           Data.Massiv.Array.Manifest.Vector as A
import           Data.Massiv.Core.Scheduler
import           Data.Typeable
import           Data.Vector.Algorithms.Merge
import           Data.Vector.Generic               as VG
import           Data.Vector.Generic.Mutable       as VGM
import           System.IO.Unsafe

sortRows ::
     forall r e v.
     (Ord e, Typeable v, A.Mutable r Ix2 e, VG.Vector v e, ARepr v ~ r, VRepr r ~ v)
  => Array r Ix2 e
  -> Array r Ix2 e
sortRows arr = unsafePerformIO $ do
  mv :: VG.Mutable v RealWorld e <- VG.thaw (A.toVector arr :: v e)
  let comp = getComp arr
      sz@(m :. n) = size arr
  case comp of
    Seq -> do
      loopM_ 0 (< m) (+ 1) $ \i -> sort $ VGM.slice (toLinearIndex sz (i :. 0)) n mv
    ParOn wIds ->
      withScheduler_ wIds $ \scheduler -> do
        loopM_ 0 (< m) (+ 1) $ \i ->
          scheduleWork scheduler $ sort $ VGM.slice (toLinearIndex sz (i :. 0)) n mv
  v :: v e <- VG.unsafeFreeze mv
  return $ A.fromVector comp sz v
```

I did add this to examples in massiv in this [commit](https://github.com/lehins/massiv/commit/0bd14a1749315fadf30222cf4bc7d08f7c63e1fa) together with a simple property test.